# Rails Error: New Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to start a new project in Rails, but I keep getting the following error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
        from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

What do I do to fix this???

Comment: Your post is tagged rvm, but it doesn't look like you are using your rvm from the error that you are getting.  That looks like the rails command is trying to use the globally installed ruby...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
sudo gem install railties
```